# Re-Shape dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary with two dimensional keys:

{('a','b'):2,('a','d'):3,('b','e'):4,('b','f'):5}.

Would like to create a nested dictionary like

{'a':{'b': 2,'d':3},'b':{'e':4, 'f':5}

Is there a smart way of doing this (instead of using loop)?

Answer (score 1):

### Using loop and defaultdict

I'm not sure you can do this without a loop, but you can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here and unpack all of the keys and values:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

something = {('a','b'):2,('a','d'):3,('b','e'):4,('b','f'):5}

for (k, k1), v in something.items():
    d[k][k1] = v

print(d)
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'a': {'b': 2, 'd': 3}, 'b': {'e': 4, 'f': 5}})
```

### Dict comprehension and itertools groupby

Alternatively, you can use a dict comprehension on the results of [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```py
from itertools import groupby

something = {('a','b'):2,('a','d'):3,('b','e'):4,('b','f'):5}

d = dict((i, {k1: v for (k, k1), v in x}) for i,x in groupby(something.items(), key = lambda x: x[0][0]))

{'a': {'b': 2, 'd': 3}, 'b': {'e': 4, 'f': 5}}
```

Where the `keyfunc` groups by what is `k` in the native defaultdict loop

### Timing

#### defaultdict

```py
python -m timeit -s 'import defaultdictloop as lp; something=lp.something' 'lp.defaultdict_loop(something)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.557 usec per loop
```

#### itertools

```py
python -m timeit -s 'import defaultdictloop as lp; something=lp.something' 'lp.itertools_loop(something)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.56 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using list comprehensions and itertools.groupby instead of explicit loops.

```
import itertools as it

d={('a','b'):2,('a','d'):3,('b','e'):4,('b','f'):5}

d_items=[[k[0],k[1],v] for k,v in d.items()]

d_items=sorted(d_items, key=lambda x: x[0])

new_d=dict((k,dict(tuple(v))) for k,v in it.groupby(d_items,lambda x: x.pop(0)))

print(new_d)

{'a': {'b': 2, 'd': 3}, 'b': {'e': 4, 'f': 5}}
```

Comment: No need to collect the items, sort them, then do `groupby`, as you can just use `groupby` and the `dict` constructor. Otherwise you risk losing a ton of time adding in a lot of implicit loops